# Why POST and GET method Form Not Working on PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

This is the index.php:

```
 header('Location:media.php?module=home');
```

I called this media.php:

```
    <html>  
    <head>      
    <title>Test media</title>   
    </head>     
    <body>
    <table width="960"  border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><img src="images/cms/header.png" width="780" height="77"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td width="200" valign="top" bgcolor="#1e2528">
     <?php include "menu.php"; ?>
     <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
      <td width="760" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <p>
      <?php include "content.php"; ?>
       <br>
      </p>    
      </td>
      </tr>
   </table>     
</body> 
</html>
```

And this is the problem, content.php:

```
   <table width="100%" cellspacing=5>
    <?php
    include_once 'include/config.php';
    include_once 'admin/include/date_lib.php';
    include_once 'class/class_lib.php';
    include_once 'class/paging.php';
    $action = new DB();
    $action->db_connect();



 if ($_GET[module]=='home'){
     </td></tr>";
      echo "<tr><td align=center>Headline News<br><br></td></tr>";
    elseif ($_GET[module]=='request'){
      echo "<tr><td class=judul_head>&#187; Hubungi Kami</td></tr>";

      echo "<tr><td class=isi>Silahkan hubungi kami secara online:</td></tr>";  

      echo "<form action='?module=sendemail' method='post'>  
            <tr><td class=isi>Name   : <input type=text name=name size=35></td></tr>
            <tr><td class=isi>E-mail : <input type=text name=email size=35></td></tr>
            <tr><td class=isi>Subject: <input type=text name=subject size=50></td></tr>
            <tr><td class=isi>Message  : <br><textarea name=message rows=13 cols=70>

</textarea></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type=submit value=Send></td></tr>
            </form>";

        echo "<tr><td class=back><br>
            [ <a href=javascript:history.go(-1)>Back</a> ]</td></tr>";            
    }




  elseif ($_GET[module]=='sendemail'){
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO email(name,
                                       email,
                                       subject,
                                       message,
                                       date) 
                            VALUES('$_GET[name]',
                                   '$_GET[email]',
                                   '$_GET[subject]',
                                   '$_GET[message]',
                                   '$today_date')");



 echo "<tr><td class=header_head>&#187; Status Email</td></tr>
        <tr><td class=isi>Email has been sent</td></tr>
        <tr><td class=back><br>
        [ <a href=index.php>Back</a> ]</td></tr>";            
}
```

I have an email form using post method. But when I click the submit button
it will be like this on url address bar

```
http://staging/media.php?name=Test+name&email=Test+email&subject=test+subject&,message=Test+message
```

Just like when I use get method. But if change `$_POST` to `$_GET` at the query. It doesn't work.

Is there something missing on my script? Or is it because I use the `$_GET[module]` method to call on same page?

Comment: please mark an answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

`if ($_GET[module]=='home'){
         </td></tr>";`
It seems to me you're missing `echo "` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have chosen to have the form method to be set as 'post', the values you're getting from the form in your mysql_query need to be $_POST instead of $_GET. Hoped that helped!

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. And yes i'm a new to web programming. After long search on my script. i've found that i also have form tags before email form. and i forgot to give </form> to earlier form. @NADH thanks for your tips. The basic is the key.

Answer (score 2):

You're also missing a bracket before the `elseif ($_GET[module]=='request')`
May I recommend a syntax highlighting editor. Becomes very easy to find this stuff.

It's also not good to mix HTML output and script together.

Answer (score 0):

GET and POST are two different things and shouldn't be thought of as interchangeable.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Using $_GET variables within a PHP script allows you to parse and "get" the URL paramaters (often the query string or folder arguments with mod_rewrite), while $_POST variables allow you to collect the transfered data.

Furthermore, if you are submitting an HTTP request to an API, or your own script, it should be a POST request... because you're submitting data. If you are trying to access an API, or your own script, and only retrieving (not creating/updating/deleting) data you should use a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

> when I click the submit button it will be like this on url address bar [...] Just like when I use get method.

Then your form is not correct. Is it the only form on the page (use View Source from your browser) and is it not nested in another form?

Also keep all the hints from the other answers in mind. While they may not immediately solve your problem, it'll become easier to hunt it down when your code is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Your setting the method of the form to be `POST` and then in the following code your trying to access the data using `$_GET` (`GET method`) which only contains the `module=sendmail`
To access the data from the submitted form you need to use `$_POST` (i.e. `POST method`).
Also the code is not properly written :

- Input tag should be like : `<input type="value" name="value" />`
- Form tag should be like : `<form method="post" action="http://complete/link/page.php?media=sendmail"></form>`

It is a good practice to specify complete URLs for the `action` attribute.